# Django signal to convert video is running even if I update other fields without updating the video file field. Is there a way to change that?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

Hey guys I am facing a problem with the signal to convert videos running  everytime I update other fields in the video model. Is is possible to change this problem. I want the video processing to run only when I upload the video file field and not any other.

This is the signal.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=VideoPost)
def convert_video(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    enqueue(tasks.convert_all_videos, instance._meta.app_label, instance._meta.model_name, instance.pk)
    print('Done converting!')
```

please do let me know if more information is needed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`post_save` can not get old data (just `pre_save` can do it), so you should update the `save` method in your model to compare old data with new data without `signal`.

```
class VideoPost(models.Model):
    ....
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        old = type(self).objects.get(pk=self.pk) if self.pk else None
        super(VideoPost, self).save(*args, **kw)

        if not old:
            # Do something when creating a new one

        if old and old.some_video_field != self.some_video_field: # Field has changed
            # Do something to convert video for the video field is updated
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Can I have this signal function inside the save function? Else I would have to remove the package and try to do the conversion manually.

Comment: The `save` method always executes when you create/update your instance, so no need `signal` here. You can move `enqueue(...)` to `save` method.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. let me try it out!

Comment: Yah, waiting for your feedback

Comment: The some_video_field should be the video file field right? 
I have given it like that, but it isn't detecting the new file and is not getting updated. the other fields when changed are getting updated.

Comment: I changed the old and old.some_field to old or old.some_video_field.. but there is another problem. How do I define the instance here for enqueue to run? I tried self.instance but it is showing error.

Comment: Let try to debug the value of your file field between old and new. Is it different? How about other fields?

Comment: I checked the logic and its working fine without any problem now. The only error is this: name 'instance' is not defined. How to define the instance here?

Comment: `instance` is `self`.

Comment: yes, it worked with self when I  changed it. sorry to update it here.